# utf error on f.read()) in database script

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

im working on one of my first bigger python flask web projects and im getting this error when im trying to compile:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py:497: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  handlers = self.handler_cache.get(filename)*
with this error and since im using visual studios to develop in, i get the breakpoint here:

```
def init_db():
with app.app_context():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql',mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read()) //ERROR on last )
    db.commit()
```

as im quiet new to python in general ive tried to look for a spesific answer, but cant find one that solves the problem. 
my imports are:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
   from datetime import datetime
   from FlaskWebProject2 import app
   import sqlite3
   from flask import Flask, request, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, jsonify
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the error.

Was caused by a , mistake in the sql file which causes the database script to crash while initializing